# django form input range how to show value?

Tags: django, forms, input

I have a question about range input in Django 2.
How can I display the current value of the input range slider?
Now its only slider without any values. Maby I should save value every time it changes, but I'm looking for simplicity.

Form:

```
scale = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type':'range', 'step': '5', 'min': '-100', 'max': '100'}), required=False)
```

Template:

{{form.scale}}

[this how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmknn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an ID attribute to your Slider so that the script can recognize this element.

```
scale = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type':'range', 'step': '5', 'min': '-100', 'max': '100', 'id':'myRange'}), required=False)
```

And then in template add:

```
<div>
  # This is how your element will be rendered
  <input type="range" min="-100" step="5" max="100" value="50"  id="myRange">

  # ADD THIS
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

# AND ALSO THIS
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

There is another example here:
https://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html