# Django Model Field for html5 Range Slider

Tags: django

I'm looking for a Django Model Field to render a HTML5 range slider like:

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
```

This question comes close to [Which Django Form Field can provide me a HTML output of <input type="range" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772684/which-django-form-field-can-provide-me-a-html-output-of-input-type-range) but it asks for a form where I would search for an admin field for Django Admin.

Further this discussion shows as well how to use an IntegerField as range slider in forms:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20674

Long story short, can I use forms in Django Admin, or is there already a specific range field?

Comment: You can write your own custom widget to do this. You are not limited to the widgets that Django itself offers. In fact a lot of packages define custom widgets.

Comment: Instead of using a range slider you can user `IntegerField` in the model and set the `MinValueValidator` and `MaxValueValidator` validations to that field.

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem, I will dive into the docs. Ajay Lingayat thanks for your reply as well. But validation is not what I'm looking for but a visual slider.

Answer (score 10):

You can implement a widget, just like Django implements widgets. For example the [**`NumberInput`** widget <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L303-L305) looks like:

> ```python
> class NumberInput(Input):
>     input_type = 'number'
>     template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/number.html'
> ```

We can do this ourselves, for example with a:

```python
# app_name/widgets.py

from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput

class RangeInput(NumberInput):
    input_type = 'range'
```

then you can use this widget with:

```python
# app_name/forms.py

from app_name.widgets import RangeInput

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myint = forms.IntegerField(widget=RangeInput)
```

Comment: thanks for this @Willem Van Onsem  Where I'm unsure is, how I would use your solution in admin forms. this is my first take of a django admin field subclassing integerField as well https://github.com/t-book/django-range-field In case your way can work with django admin this looks much easier

Comment: @toni: you can specify a `form` in your `ModelAdmin`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am attempting to apply your solution as all other descriptions I have found are incomplete and significantly more complicated. I have problems using your provided sample code. I have created a widgets.py file and coded the “from Django.django.forms.widgets  … “. This results in the following error when I start the server: .. \mysite\polls\widgets.py", line 4, in <module>    from django.django.forms.widgets import NumberInput, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.django'.

Comment: If I replace “Django.django” with in widgets.py, with a single “Django”, the error  message goes away when the module is saved and Django reloads the app. If I code in forms.py “from app_name.widgets import RangeWidget … “ I get error message when I save: “ImportError: cannot import name 'RangeWidget' from 'polls.widgets' (C:.. \mysite\polls\widgets.py)”.

Comment: But when I change code in forms.py to “from polls.widgets import RangeInput … “ the error message disappear upon save of form.py and reload of app.

Comment: Next question is how to code the view to use this slider? I’m guessing something like: 
def p2slider(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SliderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() ??????
            context = {'form' : form} ????
            return render(request, 'pollapp2/p2slider.html',context)
    else:
        form = SliderForm ()
    context = {'form' : form}  ??????
    return render(request, 'pollapp2/ p2slider.html', context)

Comment: By "making the error messages go away" I don't think I have actually "fixed" anything. Any guidance on how I can get your code to work for me will be much appreciated.

Comment: @CliveLong: this here is a simple `Form`, you should use a `ModelForm` if you want to save the form (a simple form has no `.save()` method). Thanks to report the import problems. That is now fixed.

Comment: I am trying to build the template to make use of all of this. In https://pastebin.com/WBwFLQit , I have pasted: link to widgets documentation page, forms.py, views.py, template, and a ModelForm (VoteForm) that I have successfully used to capture data from text fields and write the values into my model/ database table. The code does not throw any errors but the template does not display a slider. I am guessing (unsuccessfully) what to code on the template because I can't find what I need on the widgets documentation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem From this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006965/django-form-input-range-how-to-show-value I have seen by coding {{form.myint}} a slider appears on the rendered page. This makes sense because the view, p2slider, has the lines: form = SliderForm(), context = {'form' : form}, and the template then takes the value from the variable "form", passed by context to replace {{form.myint}}, in this case "form" points to Class SliderForm and "myint" is defined within the class. Now I have to work out how to "retrieve" the value and write it to the model.

Comment: I'm thinking the action all happens in the view. I am now studying Django views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have managed to get a slider to display and to "trap" and display the value of slider associated with its position  by using some HTML / Javascript code from W3Schools. See: https://pastebin.com/xqjiKtPg . I am trying to find how to paste a screen image into pastebin.